# Adding to mutiple string a space at the end

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a list of string I want to perform on them a modification by adding at the end a space.

First of all I want to uppercase all the string, I was able to do it, but if there's a way to combine both the sed it will be awesome

```
 sed  '
s/Hugh:/HUGH:/g ; 
s/Lory:/LORY:/g;
s/Melody:/MELODY:/g;
s/Tifany:/TIFANY:/g;
s/Henry:/HENRY:/g;
s/Jack:/JACK:/g;

'  |  sed '
s/HUGH:/HUGH: /g ; 
s/LORY:/LORY: /g;
s/MELODY:/MELODY: /g;
s/TIFANY:/TIFANY: /g;
s/HENRY:/HENRY: /g;
s/JACK:/JACK: /g;
'
```

The initial input:

```
Hugh:IS MISSING 
Lory:Is Doing well 
Tifany:Is sick
Melody:Is back 
Henry:is Dead 
Jack:is sleeping
```

The result at the moment is

```
Hugh:IS MISSING 
LORY:Is Doing well 
TIFANY:Is sick
MELODY:Is back 
HENRY:is working 
JACK:is sleeping
```

What I want is

```
Hugh: IS MISSING 
LORY: Is Doing well 
TIFANY: Is sick
MELODY: Is back 
HENRY: is working 
JACK: is sleeping
```

I want to add a space couldn't figure out how to do it, and if possible to combine the first sed and the second one by creating only one sed or awk. It will be awesome.

Comment: Why not first convert lower case to upper case and then insert a space after each `:` ? The command you posted [works for me on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/GleamingSteelblueParallelcompiler) except that `Jack` in the input is lacking the `:`, but I guess that's a typo. If you want to just combine the two `sed` scripts, just remove the `'  |  sed '` part.

Comment: @KamilCuk Cause on my file sometimes the string is perfectly written ( Uppercased ), that's why i need first of all to uppercase the wrong ones and after that add to all my string a space at the end, but by adding a space at the end it's not working with sed.

Comment: Yes, but you can just `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` all the chars to uppercase, why not? You can do the same with `sed` and `y` command and listing all the chars. Why list them the elements separately in `s/bla/BLA:/`? Where is the "end"? You posted only a single line. The code you posted, it does work for the input you presented. Is there something missing you are not telling?

Comment: `Hugh:IS MISSING` is really missing

Comment: Except for the `hugh` that is missing in the output, [your code still works for me on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/GleamingSteelblueParallelcompiler).

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with `sed` quite easily with a couple of capture groups and a couple of backreferences along with `\U` (for uppercase) and `\L` (for lowercase), e.g.

```
sed 's/\(^\w*\):\(.*$\)/\U\1: \L\2/' file
```

Above the first capture group is anchored to the beginning of line with `'^'` and captures all word-characters `\w`, then a `':'` and then to the end of line.

The replacement converts everything to uppercase with `\U`, adds a space after `':'` and then converts the rest to lowercase with `\L`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed 's/\(^\w*\):\(.*$\)/\U\1: \L\2/' file
HUGH: is missing
LORY: is doing well
TIFANY: is sick
MELODY: is back
HENRY: is dead
JACK: is sleeping
```

*Using Extended Regex*

The roughly equivalent, but slightly more robust command using *Extended Regular Expressions* would be:

```
sed -E 's/(^\w+):(.*$)/\U\1: \L\2/'
```

Where the `'+'` repetition requires 1-or-more word character to match rather than the `'*'` (zero-or-more) match with *Basic Regular Expressions*, and you do not have to escape the capture group `(...)`. Downside is not all support ERE, but most do with either the `-E` or `-r` option.

(**note:** no, I don't know what happened to `"Hugh"` in your example -- should he be deleted?)

Answer (score 1):

Gnu awk :

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=": "} # Changes the separator
    $1=toupper($1) # Converts lower to upper
' <file>
```

Result :

```
HUGH: IS MISSING 
LORY: Is Doing well 
TIFANY: Is sick
MELODY: Is back 
HENRY: is Dead 
JACK: is sleeping
```

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit Please check my updated answer

Comment: This is not working, i only want to perform this only to the string i listed on my question. 

Don't want to add a space to all ":" just the one listed above

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit your question is really unclear. Do you want to remove Hugh line from the input or do you want to not apply the change on Hugh line ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(hugh|lory|melody|tifany|henry|jack):/\U& /Ig' file
```

or, more loosely:

```
sed 's/^\S*:/\U& /' file
```